# Cycle navigation between stacks - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I want to know how can I make a navigation in React Native using React navigation between three `stackNavigators` in a cycle (`stacksNavigators` call each Other).
I am using React Native 0.44.3, React 16.0.0-alpha.6

```
export let AStack = StackNavigator({
  A: {
    screen: ecranA,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },

  Cstack: {
    screen: CStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },

});

export let BStack = StackNavigator({
  B: {
    screen: ecranB,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },

  Astack: {
    screen: AStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },

});

export let CStack = StackNavigator({
  C: {
    screen: ecranC,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },

  Bstack: {
    screen: BStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },

});
```